# Rails / Webbynode: Database push with postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webbynode

When I do

```
webbynode database push
```

Webbynode looks for a mysql database, how do I make it look for postgresql instead ?
My webbynode and the app are both setup for postgresql.

This is the error message I get:

```
ERROR: Invalid MySQL credentials for your local database (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2))
Stopping taps server...
```

Comment: Show error messages and any relevant configuration. As written this is too incomplete for an answer to be more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From webbynode: 
The database pull and push feature is still in beta and it doesn't support PostgreSQL yet.